# Importar Archivo Microsoft Excel (.xlsx) en laravel problemas

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, jobs

Tengo un archivo Microsoft Excel (.xlsx) con mas de 90.000 registro que se necesitan actualizar

Estoy trabajando con laravel 8 y mysql estoy tratando de importar dicho archivo con laravel excel 3.1, usando las funciones que proporciona:

Este es mi function del controlador en la que solo importo 2 columnas que necesito

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required'
        ]);
        $file = $this->uploadDocumentos($request->file('file'));

    (new OcupacionImport)->queue($file, 'public');
    }

protected function uploadDocumentos(UploadedFile $file)  : string
    {
        return $file->store('imports', ['disk' => 'public']);
    }
```

Mi class import:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Ocupacion;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class OcupacionImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading, ShouldQueue
{
    use Importable;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        //dd($row);
        return new Ocupacion([
            'code' => $row['code'],
            'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
        ]);
    }

    
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

El problema es que no hace la importación antes se agregaba a la tabla Jobs y allí se ejecutaba la subida en segundo plano pero ahora no lo hace.

**Nota:** el archivo si lo sube y lo guarda en el directorio store indicado

Comment: No es necesario hacer lo siguiente: `->queue($file, 'public');`, simplemente debes pasarle la ruta y ya `->queue($file)`